# PowerMockito Unfinished Stubbing Exception

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito, stubbing

I have a private method which can throw multiple exceptions. I'm trying to write test cases for the exceptions. Below code shows two test cases. Each of these, when run individually give success without any issues. But when the whole test class is run as JUnit test I get `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException`

Below is my code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestService.class)

public class PrivateTest {

    @MockBean
    private TestService1 testService1;

    @MockBean
    private XService xService;

    @MockBean
    private YService yService;

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class ServiceTestContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public TestService TestService() {
            return PowerMockito.spy(new TestService());
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        assertNotNull(xService);
        assertNotNull(yService);
        assertNotNull(testService1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCoordinatesFromMacIOException() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(testService, “methoToCall”, Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
        ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> r = TestService.getDesired(Constant.value1, Constant.value2);
        assertEquals(r.getStatusCodeValue(), 500);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCoordinatesFromMacOAuthSigner() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.doThrow(new OAuthMessageSignerException("Test Error")).when(testService, "methoToCall", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
                ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> r = TestService.getDesired(Constant.value1, Constant.value2);
        assertEquals(r.getStatusCodeValue(), 500);
    }

}
```

StackTrace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.core.classloader.ClassloaderWrapper.runWithClassClassLoader(ClassloaderWrapper.java:51)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed

    at com.testService.service.TestService.methoToCall.(TestService:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1852)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:816)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:681)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:149)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:132)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:141)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

How do I overcome this exception?

Comment: try to add the stacktrace

Comment: @MaciejKowalski - Added stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

From the javadocs:

> Matcher methods like `anyObject()`, `eq()` do not return matchers.
>   Internally, they record a matcher on a stack and return a dummy value
>   (usually null). This implementation is due static type safety imposed
>   by java compiler. **The consequence is that you cannot use anyObject(),
>   eq() methods outside of verified/stubbed method**

So instead of:

```
TestService.getDesired(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())
```

use (for example):

```
TestService.getDesired("", "");
```

Comment: This doesnt work in my case. For the sake of question I added any string when I posted it but the method takes certain values to execute. If I change them as mentioned above my assertion fails. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: when(TestService.. shouldnt you pass when(testService1 ?  So an actual mock?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Its a mistake in the question and I corrected it

Comment: testService is not a mock.. testService1 is